# Android How to change image inside a listview for a particular condition

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview`. I have infalted that list view with a layout file which contain a `textView` and an `imageview`.
`Textview` for that is populated from a `arraylist`. I have used an `array-adapter`,because it directly gives me the `getFilter()` which in turn i use to filter the list.

I am running a database query , which returns a list of items.I am storing all the items in a `Cursor`. Now i am iterating through the cursor and checking whether the items from the database are contained in the arraylist.

I want to toggle the image if there is a match.how do i do that.

```
Cursor crs = actSl.execSQL(sqlQuery);
 if (crs != null && crs.getCount() > 0) {
  crs.moveToFirst();
  if (crs.getCount() > 0) {
     do {
         for(String favItem:favouritesList){
               if (favItem.contains(crs.getString(0))) {                        

                            }
                        }
                    } while (crs.moveToNext());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your datastructure one way would be to create a new array(or arraylist) of boleans the size of your favouritesList that will hold status of your images. 
You then modify these values and call yourListAdapter.notifyItemsChanged()

Oh yeah, and inside getView in your adapter you have to (of course) read the booleans.

Note you cannot access the separate views of a list outside adapter and holding a reference to them is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps :

1. Initially set the imageViews from an arrayList ( Pass the arrayList to the customAdapter)
2. When an imageView has to be changed, just change the arrayList() ie update it.
3. Now notify the adapter using

   customListAdapter.notifyItemsChanged();

This will solve the problem. Please feel free to ask any further doubts

Comment: Ok then i would have to write a method for filtering the list.I can do that.Let me try this. thanx